# Receiving value by jumping by referenced indices

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm having trouble figuring out how to get values from third table, jumping by referenced indices from first to second to third. Data:

```
          Players
Player_ID| Player_Name| ...   
    1    | Adam Smith | ...  
    2    | John  Doe  | ...

              Participants
Participant_ID| Event_ID | Player_ID| ...  
      1       |     1    |     2    | ... 
      2       |     1    |     1    | ...

                              Games
Game_ID|Event_ID|White_player (patricipant id)|Black_Player (participant_id)| ...  
   1   |    1   |             1               |                 2           | ...
```

What I basically want to have:

```
   Game_ID|Event_ID|White_player (patricipant id)|Black_Player (participant_id)| ...  
   1      |    1   |        John Doe             |            Adam Smith       | ...
```

But in the end i need String like: "John Doe vs Adam Smith". I don't want to replace values in the table. I don't know if I should do this this way or maybe change my tables structure.

Comment: what's with the white and black player column?

Comment: I don't understand your question, can You explain what you mean clearer?

Comment: Exactly. What is the rule for determining `black player` and `white player`?

Comment: I create tournament, then i'm adding players that are participating in this tournament and after that i'm choosing which one is playing with which. There is no particular rule. EDIT: I forgot one column, sorry I'll edit it now.

Answer (score 0):

It is allowed to join to the same table more than once. In this case you need to join to `Players` twice, to get the names of both Black and White. So you need something like this:

```
select g.game_id
       , wp.event_id
       , p1.player_name 
         || ' vs ' ||
         p2.player_name as competitors
from games g
     join participants wp
         on wp.event_id = g.game_id
         and wp.participant_id = g.white_player
     join players p1
         on wp.participant_id = p1.player_id
     join participants bp
         on bp.event_id = g.game_id
         and bp.participant_id = g.black_player
     join players p2
         on bp.participant_id = p2.player_id
```

Comment: Your joins aren't quite right.  The white/black player columns are in `games`, not `participants`.

Comment: I noticed that, and corrected it myself: `select (p1.first_name || ' ' || p1.surname || ' vs ' || p2.first_name || ' ' || p2.surname) as competitors, g.game_id
        
from games g
     join players p1
         on g.white_player = p1.player_id
     join players p2
         on g.black_player = p2.player_id
         
where g.event_id = :P1_TOURNAMENT
`

Comment: But i still need to replace white and black players id as player id from participants table

Answer (score 0):

After some fixes I've got result I wanted:

```
select p1.player_name || ' vs ' || p2.player_name as competitors, g.game_id
from games g
     join participants_list wp
         on wp.event_id = g.event_id
         and wp.participant_id = g.white_player
     join players p1
         on wp.player_id= p1.player_id
     join participants_list bp
         on bp.event_id = g.event_id
         and bp.participant_id = g.black_player
     join players p2
         on bp.player_id = p2.player_id
```